# Is a stepper motor the best option - if not what

Tags: stepper-motor

I have a project where I want to have a 3-400kg mass rotate around its axis.
Based on my calculations, I am looking for a hold torque of approx 100-120Nm

I have considered having a worm drive involved, but the requirement to rotate one way, hold or immediately rotate the other way makes me think that the process will be sloppy with a worm drive in it.

Anyone know where I can find a stepper motor that can achieve my goal, or can you suggest an alternative process.

For the record, this is what I am trying to build

https://youtu.be/wAI02_B6WpY

Thanks

Comment: Stepper motor doesn't have a lot of torque, you can have a look at brushless motors.

Comment: How accurate has it to be? What is the budget? Stepper is cheap, and as any cheap device it has many drawbacks, but maybe you don't care

Comment: That looks fun. You want a geared-down servo motor, with a lot of power, in a position maintaining feedback loop. Hint, loop stability will not be trivial.

Comment: That's a very expensive servo drive system. PMSM with gearbox.

Comment: According to the video, your mass (human) is not centered (so you are not rotating it around its axis!). This will require a BIG motor!

Comment: Damien Does a brushless motor give the ability to hold the full mass at 90 deg off horizontal, for some time? Where would I learn more?

GregoryKornblum - you can see what I am trying to achieve - anything that achieves this will be fine. I am anticipating $AUD 20k/ USD15k for the entire project - obviously the less expensive the better :)

MarkoBuršič Where would I learn more about what you describe?

WoutervanOoijen I have taken that into consideration - as I understand it, an off-centre centre of gravity, increases the torque requirements only, is that how you see it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a worm drive. 100N-m is a huge amount of torque for a hobby motor. To avoid errors accumulating from backlash (‘slop’) you will need to directly sense the position of the output gear, e.g with an optical encoder, resolver, or magnetic encoder.

Comment: Where would I find more information on the encoder/resolver process?

Comment: @Irish_Kiwi https://www.machinedesign.com/sensors/basics-rotary-encoders-overview-and-new-technologies-0